# Gmail connection error 10061 rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, gmail

I'm trying to send devise confirmation emails from my Rails 3.2 app. However when it is sent I get the following error:

> 421 Cannot connect to SMTP server, connect error 10061

Im currently using these configuration settings in my enviroments/development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :domain         => 'gmail.com',
    :port           => 587,
    :user_name      => 'emailAdress@gmail.com',
    :password       => 'password',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Is there something missing in the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that if you are doing this from localhost, your domain is wrong. It should be something like this:

```
:domain => "localhost.localdomain"
```

In general, you would want to have something like this:

```
:domain =>'your.host.name'
```